# d3 js with scale and zoom in zoom out

Tags: d3.js

Using below d3 js code draw scale, but not able to figure out how i can convert x-axis dates to hours on zoom, trying to achieve x-axis dates get converted into hours on zoom in and on zoom out again into dates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
    }))
  .append("g");



// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

    data = [{
                date:"1-May-12",
                close:"58.13"
             },
             {
                date:"30-Apr-12",
                close:"53.98"
             },{
                date:"27-Apr-12",
                close:"67.00"
             },{
                date:"26-Apr-12",
                close:"89.70"
             }
          ]

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis


});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't fully understand your question. Have you seen the [Brush & Zoom](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172) example?

Answer (score 0):

In a callback that implements the zoom event. You only transform the svg object. you have to process axis also. It seems that you have an effect of axis zooming.

```
xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)
gX.call(xAxis.scale(xScale))
```

It rescales the scaler according to the zoom event and than the axis is rescaled and is applied to the axis group container.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly this, but in v3 (same as above question). Do you know how I can implement axis zoom in v3, which does not have “d3.event.transform” or “rescaleX”?